# Using rep inside a map function to make data larger

Tags: r

I have a list in which I apply the following `map` to:

```
modified_list <- map(boundary_lists,
    ~tibble(
      x = seq(.x$minX, .x$maxX, length.out = 200),
      y = seq(.x$minY, .x$maxY, length.out = 200)
    )
)
```

I am trying to expand this by adding the following:

```
rep(modified_list[[1]]$x, each = 200)
rep(modified_list[[1]]$y, time = 200)
```

I have tried:

```
map(modified_list, ~mutate(.,
                           xx = rep(.x$x, each = 200),
                           yy = rep(.y$y)
                           )
            )
```

Which returns an error. How can I add the `rep()` to the mapped `tibble()`?

Data:

```
    boundary_lists <- list(structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, 
    minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
> boundary_lists %>% dput()
list(structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, 
    minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, 
        minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, 
        minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, 
        minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, 
        minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, 
        minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `map`, there is only `.x` (in `map2`, it would be `.x`, `.y` as two parameters are passed into).  Also, `rep`licating within `mutate` can result in error as `mutate` returns the same `length` as the original number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
map(modified_list, ~tibble(
                       xx = rep(.x$x, each = 200),
                       yy = rep(.x$y, each = 200)
                       )
        )
```

---

Or a clean option is

```
map(modified_list, uncount, weights = 200)
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
lapply(modified_list, function(dat) dat[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)), each = 200), ])
```